# cannot use the Unity Tweak Tool

Tags: 15.04, unity-tweak-tool

I can't change themes in my Ubuntu 15.04 after update. It says:

```
The following schema is missing
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad
```

I've used the dconf editor but touchpad doesn't appear.
Mouse and keyboard setting also doesn't open.

Comment: Are you able to use touchpad, mouse etc..?

Comment: Same issue for me. Very annoying.

Answer (score 11):

It's a configuration error in UTT. 
You need to update some configuration files to use:

```
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad
```

instead of

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad
```

Just open terminal and type:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/lib/python3/site-packages/UnityTweakTool/section/system.py
```

Then change the following lines so they look like:

- Line 182: `'schema' : 'org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad',`
- Line 193: `'schema' : 'org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad',`
- Line 205: `'schema' : 'org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad',`

Save changes, close gedit and, again in terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/lib/python3/site-packages/UnityTweakTool/section/spaghetti/gsettings.py
```

Change the following line to:

- Line 114 (in 15.10 its line 120): `touch = gnome('desktop.peripherals.touchpad')`

Save and exit.
UnityTweakTool should now start without problems.

**Note:**

If you can't find `/usr/lib/python3/site-packages/`, then you should have `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` instead.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 15.10, thank you.

Comment: For 15.10, has someone filed it as bug? I will if not.

Comment: Thanks! This worked under Ubuntu 15.10 as well. Alternatively, one can enter these two command in a terminal window: `sudo sed -i "s/org\.gnome\.settings\-daemon\.peripherals\.touchpad/org\.gnome\.desktop\.peripherals\.touchpad/g" "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/section/system.py"` and `sudo sed -i "s/org\.gnome\.settings\-daemon\.peripherals\.touchpad/org\.gnome\.desktop\.peripherals\.touchpad/g" "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/section/spaghetti/gsettings.py"`

Comment: both site-packages and dist-packages lead me to empty python files

Answer (score 2):

The missing schemas are provided by the [gnome-settings-daemon-schemas](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/gnome-settings-daemon-schemas) package.

Try to reinstall it with (in a terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-settings-daemon-schemas
```

The schemas should now be installed in:

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.gschema.xml
```

Comment: For me, this did not work. Still the same error and the mouse and kb settings still don't open.

Comment: I reinstalled as above with no fix.  Reading the schema in gedit, I found 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad.deprecated' but not the missing schema itself (no '.deprecated').  Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: This issue still exists in Xenial. This solution (minor change - install, not reinstall) fixed it.

Comment: @beachbuddah https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/cursor-location-in-20-04-4-ubuntu-lts-via-dconf-4175715691/#post6374143 GNOME 4.0 deprecated a bunch of things.